# CustomSquare layout null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am facing issue when i try to access the textview id from layout and set that id in  my adapter class. It gives null pointer exception .How do I access the textview in adapter class.

Following is the code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridCatalogProductContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <com.android.ordering.newui.CustomSquareLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gridViewImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/catalog_image_selector" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gridCatalogProducttNametextView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/header_background"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gridViewImageTitle"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/catalog_image_size"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="@style/white_text_appearance"
            android:textSize="@dimen/grid_item_text_view_size" />
    </com.android.emobilepos.ordering.newui.CustomSquareLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Below is my complete adapter class code where i got the crash when trying to set data in textview.

```
public class ProductCatalogAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private final String attrToDisplay;
    private final DisplayImageOptions options;
    private OrderingMainCallback callback;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    MyPreferences preferences;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public ProductCatalogAdapter(OrderingMainCallback callback, Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
        this.callback = callback;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        preferences = new MyPreferences(context);
        this.imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        File cacheDir = new File(preferences.getCacheDir());
        if (!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).memoryCacheExtraOptions(100, 100)
                .discCacheExtraOptions(1000, 1000, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, null).discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)).build();
        imageLoader.init(config);
        imageLoader.handleSlowNetwork(true);
        attrToDisplay = preferences.getPreferencesValue(MyPreferences.pref_attribute_to_display);
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().resetViewBeforeLoading(true).displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer()).cacheOnDisc(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.loading_image)
//                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.no_image)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View retView;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.catalog_listview_adapter, parent, false);
        holder.title = retView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewImageTitle);
        holder.itemImage = retView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewImage);
        holder.productNameTxt = retView.findViewById(R.id.gridCatalogProducttNametextView);
        holder.prodNameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(attrToDisplay);
        holder.prodIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
        holder.prodImgNameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex("prod_img_name");
        retView.setTag(holder);
        return retView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {
        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();


        holder.productNameTxt.setText(cursor.getString(holder.prodNameIdx));
        holder.productNameTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        holder.title.setText(cursor.getString(holder.prodNameIdx));
        String urlLink = cursor.getString(holder.prodImgNameIdx);
//        holder.itemImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                if (preferences.isFastScanningMode()) {
//                    callback.addProduct(cursor.getString(holder.prodIdIdx));
//                }
//            }
//        });
        imageLoader.displayImage(urlLink, holder.itemImage, options, new ImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String s, View view) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
                    holder.productNameTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.itemImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }else {
                    holder.productNameTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.itemImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String s, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                holder.productNameTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.itemImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String s, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
                    holder.productNameTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.itemImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }else {
                    holder.productNameTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.itemImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingCancelled(String s, View view) {

            }
        });
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(urlLink)){

        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        CustomSquareLayout customSquareLayout;
        TextView title, productNameTxt;
        ImageView itemImage;
        int prodNameIdx;
        public int prodIdIdx;
        int prodImgNameIdx;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the entire Adapter class.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <com.android.ordering.newui.CustomSquareLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

 </com.android.emobilepos.ordering.newui.CustomSquareLayout>
```

> Your CustomSquareLayout start and end is not same i.e the package path is different and should be same.

Comment: still i got the null pointer exception

Comment: In that case you have to share your whole code including the custom class.